# How to test .pipe with jest with rxjs

Tags: typescript, jestjs, rxjs, nestjs

I have the following service to test

```
const { data: plan } = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .post<CreatePlanPagarmeInterface>(
          `${PagarmeConfig.baseUrl}/plans`,
          pagarmeBody,
          PagarmeConfig.auth,
        )
        .pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            throw new BadRequestException(
              'Error to create plan.',
            );
          }),
        ),
    );
```

My test

```
 describe('createPlanMonth', () => {
    it('shoud be able to create a new plan month', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post').mockReturnValueOnce(
        of({
          status: 200,
          statusText: 'OK',
          config: {},
          headers: {},
          data: resultPagarmeMock,
        }),
      );

      const result = await planService.createPlanMonth(mockPlan);

      expect(result).toEqual(resultMockPlan);
    });
  });
```

however I'm getting an error when the test arrives in the .pipe

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')

Comment: You need to post the full service.  The "service" you posted isn't returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
const response: AxiosResponse<any> = {
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    config: {},
    headers: {},
    data: resultPagarmeMock,
  };


describe('createPlanMonth', () => {
    it('shoud be able to create a new plan month', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post').mockReturnValueOnce(
        of({
          status: 200,
          statusText: 'OK',
          config: {},
          headers: {},
          data: resultPagarmeMock,
        }),
      );

      httpService.post('', { data: mockPlan }).subscribe((res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual(response);
        expect(res.data).toHaveProperty('id');
        expect(res.data).toHaveProperty('status');
      });

      jest.spyOn(repository, 'create').mockResolvedValue(resultMockPlan);

      const result = await repository.create(resultSaveDatabase);

      expect(result).toEqual(resultMockPlan);
      expect(result).toHaveProperty('id');
      expect(result).toHaveProperty('plan_id');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `mockReturnValueOnce(of())` you'd need to use `mockReturnValueOnce(throwError(() => new AxiosError()))` where `AxiosError` is an error object that takes the same shape as axios's normal error format, it could even be the regular axios error class `import { AxiosError } from 'axios';`. This way, the observable throws the error and your `catchError` operator has something to catch and operate on.

Comment: Got it, but I don't want to catch the error, I want to successfully simulate an order.

Comment: This will simulate the error and trigger your `catchError` operator, which then `throw new BadRequestException()` as per your code